# Returning an int from an array of int java

Tags: java, arrays

I came across this interview question.

Write a program that accepts an array of integers and returns an integer whose digits consist of the numbers in that array?

For instance, if the array contains {1,2,3}, the method should return 123.

Thanks.

Currently I have this

```
public int transformArray(int [] numberArray){
        for(int i=0; i<=numberArray.length;i++){
            int number=number+number.CharAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, you've explained the question. Now all you have to do is show how you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: 123 = 1* 100 + 2 * 10 + 3. It easy to see a pattern.

Comment: And what problem do you have with this code?

Comment: The code you've given doesn't compile. An `int` doesn't have a `CharAt` method, which would be named `charAt` even if it did, and you can't declare and reference `number` in the same statement like that, and your method is declared to return `int` but doesn't return anything.

Comment: Its a stupid question (if thats the original wording): "whose digits consist of the numbers in that array". Ambiguity galore.

Comment: You need to multiply by 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate each char to a string and convert it back to int:

```
public int transformArray(int [] numberArray){
    String ans = "";        
    for(int i=0; i<=numberArray.length;i++){
      ans = ans + numberArray[i];
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(ans)
}
```

Or multiply by 10 as David Conrad suggested

```
public int transformArray(int [] numberArray){
    int ans = 0;        
    for(int i=0; i<=numberArray.length;i++){
      ans = ans * 10;
      ans = ans + numberArray[i];
    }
    return ans
}
```

Comment: Why concatenate instead of multiply by 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    result += array[i] * Math.pow(10, array.length - i - 1);
}
return result;
```

Comment: There's no need for Math.pow. There's a nice solution that just multiplies by 10 every time around the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**:

```
public String getName() {
    //create new ArrayList    
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //add numbers
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(9);

    //for each element in the list, add the number
    String s = "";
    for(int i : numbers) {
        s = s + i;
    }
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    return s;
}
```

The output of the method in this case:

```
String: 19
```

If you want the `String s` as an **Integer** use:

`int i = Integer.parseInt(s)`

Comment: It gives correct result. But far from simplest way to do this.